# SQLite3 Updating by variable ERROR Incorrect number of bindings suppllied

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update data in a table by user input. However, I get this error when, executing the function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Programming Fundamentals/TEST.py", line 396, in <module>
    post_start_up()  # Starts the post_start_up function
  File "E:/Programming Fundamentals/TEST.py", line 384, in post_start_up
    menu()
  File "E:/Programming Fundamentals/TEST.py", line 146, in menu
    menu_opt3()  # Runs the menu option 3 function
  File "E:/Programming Fundamentals/TEST.py", line 222, in menu_opt3
    c.execute(''' UPDATE tblCategory SET Category = ? WHERE CategoryID = ?'''), (cat_inpt, id_inpt)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied.
```

The code for the function being executed is:

```
def menu_opt3():
    print("You chose option 3. Update Categories.. \n")
    print("CatID, UserID, CategoryName, CategoryBudget \n")
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tblCategory")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)
    id_inpt = int(input("Please enter the ID of the category you'd like to update"))
    option_input = input("Would you like to update the name (A) or the monthly budget (B) of the category?: \n")
    if option_input == "A":
        cat_inpt = input("Please enter the new name of the category: \n")
        c.execute(''' UPDATE tblCategory SET Category = ? WHERE CategoryID = ?'''), (cat_inpt, id_inpt)
        conn.commit()
        print("Data updated successfully. \n")
        menu()
    elif option_input == "B":
        bdgt_inpt = int(input("Please enter the new monthly budget of the category: \n"))
        c.execute(''' UPDATE tblCategory SET CategoryMonthlyBudget = ? WHERE CategoryID = ?'''), (bdgt_inpt, id_inpt)
        conn.commit()
        print("Data updated successfully. \n")
        menu()
    else:
        print("Invalid user input. \n")
        menu()
```

Any help would be appreciated as it's crucial that I get this to work and it's probably only something small I missed out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.execute(''' UPDATE tblCategory SET Category = ? WHERE CategoryID = ?'''), (cat_inpt, id_inpt)
#                                                                        ^ mis-located parenthesis
```

You are closing the call to `c.execute` too early.

You are essentially calling `c.execute` with just the query and then creating a tuple which is thrown away, like

```
c.execute(query), ('useless', 'tuple')
```

That line should be

```
c.execute(''' UPDATE tblCategory SET Category = ? WHERE CategoryID = ?''', (cat_inpt, id_inpt))
```